# Generate Excel using php, format cells as string number etc

Tags: php, excel, formatting, csv

I am generating an excel file using php.

The file gets created how ever strings with leading zeros example 0234 get converted to 234.

Comment: Did you try warping those values in quotes?

Comment: How are you actually generating the file? Are you creating a CSV file with an extension of .xls? or using a library like PHPExcel or the PEAR spreadsheet writer? How to resolve the problem will depend on your answer to that question.

Answer (score 0):

you want to set the number format to text

```
Range("A1").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "@"
```

"@"

is the value for Text Format.

That should display leading 0's.

I hope that helps ;)